# Twitter mood API

Tags: php, twitter

Is there a twitter API that returns mood? I have seen some websites that return the mood of a specific tweet and I want to be able to use an API (or to use some open source code) to get the mood of a tweet, does anyone know if there is an easy way to do that or if there is an already built API for this?

Comment: @user220755: You say "If you need more information please ask me and I will edit the entry to include more information".  If that information is available, you should include it in the first place for completeness.  While there are usually quick and dirty answers, there is no such thing as a quick and dirty question.

Comment: What I meant is that sometimes people prefer getting more information before answering a question and that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to use another API to do sentiment analysis on the tweets you want to extract moods from. Open Amplify is probably a good one to start with http://community.openamplify.com/content/docs.aspx/.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the accepted answer is no longer working and the rest of the links in the other answers are all pretty useless. The best Twitter sentiment project and accompanying API is [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/twittersentimenthelp/home) from Stanford. It's better then the defunct tweetfeel.

Comment: The Twitter Sentiment project linked in this answer is now called Sentiment140. New link with latest info: http://help.sentiment140.com/

Comment: @Zoe do they charge for api call?

Comment: no they don't charge. And all the info about commercial use is here http://help.sentiment140.com/api/commercial-licensing-faq

Answer (score 0):

Most of the websites you see doing that are using a general technique called **[sentiment extraction](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=sentiment%20extraction&oe=utf-8&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&hl=en&tab=ws)**. There are many possible implementations, but a simple (somewhat naive) one is to make a list of "bad" words ("shouldn't", "angry", "evil", "allergic") and a list of "good" words ("happiness", "joyful", "smiling", "wonderful"). Assign a "mood score" to each word (or just -1 to bad words and +1 to good words). The total score is the "mood'.

This is a naive approach because many words require context to understand. (For example, a Bostonian describing something as "wicked good" is making a doubly positive remark, not canceling out the following word.) Still, it may be suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've seen any Twitter tweets mood API around, but someone made it possible through the use of Twitter API. http://i8news.uterm.org/mood/twitter-mood-reader/

The logic was to read through the tweets and by calculating the emotional words (such as "wow", "happy", "!", "darn"), you get the overall mood of that tweet.

Comment: does that application have an API that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new free API from TweetFeel that uses advanced linguistic processing to determine sentiment (mood). Take a look at http://www.webservius.com/corp/docs/tweetfeel_sentiment.htm

Answer (score 0):

I did a project involving Sentiment Analysis of Tweets. I used a machine-learning sentiment analyzer called '`LingPipe`'. Unfortunately, it requires you to design your program in Java (I know you tagged your question under PHP), and to make a fairly decent training set from your raw data (very tedious work). However, if you do have Java skills, and time, then it's fairly easy to use, and extremely speedy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of APIs/websites that implement sentiment analysis on text.

Hope it helps. :)

> https://sites.google.com/site/twittersentimenthelp/other-resources